# How can I keep logged a Django WebApp after login another WebApp using the same OIDC - IDP Authenticate?

Tags: python, authentication, django-views, openid-connect, idp

`First application: C#
no access to code

Second application: Python (Django)

`def oidc_login(request, internal=False):
if internal == "True":
request.session["next_url"] = "/servicos"
else:
sufixo_url = request.GET["next"]
request.session["next_url"] = sufixo_url

```
redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("oidc_callback"))

return oauth.idpsp.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)
```

def oidc_callback(request):
return_url = request.session["next_url"]
del request.session["next_url"]

```
token = oauth.idpsp.authorize_access_token(request)
id_token_hint = token["id_token"]
request.session["key_salt"] = id_token_hint

request.session["user"] = token["userinfo"]
userinfo = request.session["user"]
user_created = create_and_authenticate(request, userinfo)

if user_created is True:
    return redirect(return_url)

return redirect(return_url)`
```

The both app use the same OIDC - IDP login proccess, but after the user logs in to the first application, they need to validate again in the second application. I need the second application to log in automatically if I am already logged in to the first. Can you help me?

in base.html don't work
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

in View.py - dont't work
if request.user.is_authenticated:

`